# How to add instance of a class, to items in an array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a `class` called `Dog`, and it has an array property called `.puppies`. I'm trying to every item in the puppies array to be an `instanceof Dog`. How would I achieve that?

```
class Dog {
  constructor(make){
    this.name = name;
    this.puppies = [];
  }

  addPuppies(name){
    this.puppies.push(name);
  }
}

const dog = new Dog('Doug');
console.log(dog instanceof Dog); // true

dog.addPuppies('Douggy');

const douggy = dog.puppies[0];

console.log(douggy instanceof Dog); // false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `new Dog` on everything you call `addPuppies` with, else you won't have a Dog instance:

```js
class Dog {
  constructor(make){
    this.name = name;
    this.puppies = [];
  }

  addPuppies(puppy){
    this.puppies.push(puppy);
  }
}

const dog = new Dog('Doug');
console.log(dog instanceof Dog); // true

dog.addPuppies(new Dog('Douggy'));

const douggy = dog.puppies[0];

console.log(douggy instanceof Dog); // true
```

Or you could change `addPuppies` to call `new Dog` itself:

```js
class Dog {
  constructor(make){
    this.name = name;
    this.puppies = [];
  }

  addPuppies(name){
    this.puppies.push(new Dog(name));
  }
}

const dog = new Dog('Doug');
console.log(dog instanceof Dog); // true

dog.addPuppies('Douggy');

const douggy = dog.puppies[0];

console.log(douggy instanceof Dog); // true
```